# Flash actionscript guidance needed?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I am developing a flash games in which a letter symbol flies from right side of the screen and ends at left i need to process some keyboard events i.e when a  letter is on the vertical 
bar the letter should stop there. Can any one guide me how can i achieve this [image]

Abdul Khaliq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy approach is to put the created "letters" in an Array and call an update function  (TimerEvent.TIMER or Event.ENTER_FRAME) wich moves/animates the letters. If the letter is inside the vertical bar (in range of x) and the [correct key is pressed](http://blog.kazumakzak.com/2009/04/07/actionscript-keyboard-keycodes/) then you just lock it there.

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onKeyUpHandler);
private function onKeyUpHandler(event : KeyboardEvent) : void
{
    for(var i : int = 0 ; i < _letterList.length ; i++)
    {
        if(isInRange(_letterList[i]))
        {
            if(_letterList[i].validateKey(event.keyCode))
            {
                // lock on position and skip further updates
            }
        }
    }
}
```